# Kubernetes application URL location?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have run a basic example project and can confirm it is running, but I cannot identify its URL?

Kubectl describe service - gives me

```
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
frontend-6c8b5cc5b-v9jlb   1/1     Running   0          26s
PS D:\git\helm3\lab1_kubectl_version1\yaml> kubectl describe service
Name:              frontend
Namespace:         default
Labels:            name=frontend
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=frontend
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.108.59.44
IPs:               10.108.59.44
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        4200/TCP
Endpoints:         10.1.0.38:4200
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>


Name:              kubernetes
Namespace:         default
Labels:            component=apiserver
                   provider=kubernetes
Annotations:       <none>
```

Should I be able to hit this locally or not? The demo suggests yes but no URL is given and anything I attempt fails.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes: access from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61538098/kubernetes-access-from-outside)

Answer (score 3):

From outside you do not have any way to connect to your service since its type is set to `ClusterIP` if you want directly to expose your service, you should set it to either type `LoadBalancer` or `NodePort`. For more info about these types check this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types).

However your service has an internal url ( which works within the cluster, for example if you exec into a pod and curl that url, you will get a response ) and that is: `<your service>.<your namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

Instead of `<your service>` type the name of the service and instead of `<your namespace>` namespace in which that service resides. The rest of the url is the same for all services.